# Retrieve records from a log file for last n seconds in python

Tags: python, file, logging

I want to ignore "Not Found: /api" and return all GET and POST calls within the last n seconds entered

**Below is how my log file looks:**

```
Not Found: /api
[22/Aug/2018 10:07:14] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 2318
Not Found: /api
[22/Aug/2018 10:30:30] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 2318
Not Found: /api
[22/Aug/2018 10:30:33] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 2318
[22/Aug/2018 10:37:08] "POST /api/entity/ HTTP/1.1" 201 83
[22/Aug/2018 10:37:40] "GET /api/entity/ HTTP/1.1" 200 412
[22/Aug/2018 10:37:41] "POST /api/datasets/ HTTP/1.1" 201 115
```

Comment: Loop through each line and print the line `if not line.lower().startswith('not found')`

Comment: but there are other strings that comes up in the log file and also displaying last n seconds is where I am getting stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

As there are several unwanted lines in the logfile, not only "Not found...", I assume all valid lines begin with a square bracket like the date rows above.

At first, I'd read all lines which are valid into a list:

```
log = []
with open ('/wherever/file/may/roam/logfile.log', 'r') as logfile:
    for row in logfile.readlines():
        if row[0] == '[':
            log.append(row)
```

With `StringIO` from the `io`-module you can feed this into the dataframe-creation of pandas:

```
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(''.join(log)), colspecs=[(1, 21), (23, None)], header=None)
```

<del>You can read this log file with `pandas`in a dataframe like this</del>

<del>import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf('/wherever/file/may/roam/logfile.log', colspecs=[(1, 21), (23, None)], comment='o', header=None)</del>

<del>Here I used 'read fixed width file', because of the equal-length date at the beginning. I already cut off the brackets by reading from the second character on (colspecs), so the signal character for lines to be skipped via the comment keyword is the 'o' of 'Not'. Call it misuse, but it works here well. Then `header=None` is because your file has no column descriptors as a first line.</del>

Result is this dataframe:

```
df
                      0                                       1
0  22/Aug/2018 10:07:14            "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 2318
1  22/Aug/2018 10:30:30            "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 2318
2  22/Aug/2018 10:30:33            "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 2318
3  22/Aug/2018 10:37:08     "POST /api/entity/ HTTP/1.1" 201 83
4  22/Aug/2018 10:37:40     "GET /api/entity/ HTTP/1.1" 200 412
5  22/Aug/2018 10:37:41  "POST /api/datasets/ HTTP/1.1" 201 115
```

With

```
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
```

we turn the date of type string into a datetime format we can calculate with.
Then we need a function to calculate n seconds back from the last entry:

```
thrshld = lambda n: df[0].values[-1] - n*10**9
```

The datetime values in df[0] are of type numpy.datetime64, which has a nanosecond resolution, therefore the factor 10**9.

Now you can index your dataframe like

```
df[df[0]>thrshld(5)]
Out: 
                    0                                       1
4 2018-08-22 10:37:40     "GET /api/entity/ HTTP/1.1" 200 412
5 2018-08-22 10:37:41  "POST /api/datasets/ HTTP/1.1" 201 115

df[df[0]>thrshld(60)]
Out: 
                    0                                       1
3 2018-08-22 10:37:08     "POST /api/entity/ HTTP/1.1" 201 83
4 2018-08-22 10:37:40     "GET /api/entity/ HTTP/1.1" 200 412
5 2018-08-22 10:37:41  "POST /api/datasets/ HTTP/1.1" 201 115
```

Comment: ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr)
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'nternal Server Err')

Comment: this statement does not seem to be working "df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])"

Comment: Then perhaps your data contains more unwanted rows, not only the"Not found" ones. Check the content of `df[0]` if there are only date strings of the exact same form or if there are different entries.

Comment: There are statements such as " Internal Server Error: /api/datasets/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File " in the code that may be causing the error

Comment: Thank you SpghttCd but there seems to be other strings like "File "/data02/py_venvs" , "Internal Server Error:" etc in the log file. do you have any idea how to discard those in order to print only the required data

Comment: There are different entries in df[0] such as "1222     File "/data02/py_ve
1223               return _b
1224               File "<fr
1225               File "<fr
1226               File "<fr"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using tail:

`tail somelog.log | grep -E 'GET|POST'`

You may also be able to use egrep:

`tail somelog.log | egrep 'GET|POST'`

You could also `cat` the log file and pipe the same `egrep` or `grep -E` command.

Comment: how to use it in python as am not able to use tail and also how to give an input as n seconds and get the output as all the calls made in those last n seconds

Comment: We need more context to answer this question.  How are you generating and viewing the logs?  Do you have access to the directory in which they're written?  Do you need to do this entirely programatically?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: there is a logs file and i read from this logs file and display the output.

Comment: enter input as seconds and the python program should retrieve the calls made in last n seconds( GET and POST).

Comment: yes, I have access to the logs file. there are just log files. yes i need to write an entire script to retrieve this data.